# Convex hull in 4D

Tags: python-2.7, convex-hull

Suppose that four 4D points [1/3, 1/6, 1/3, 1/6], [0, 0, 1/2, 1/2],[0, 0, 0, 1], and [0, 0, 2/3, 1/3] are given. How to compute the following properties of their convex hull in Python?

1) the set of extreme points

2) projection of the convex hull onto different coordinate axes, i.e., x-axis, y-axis,... .

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Python specifically, but the algorithm you want is the [Jarvis March (aka gift-wrapping method).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) Begin by finding a known extreme point *A* (simply by comparing coordinates numerically). Then, pair this point with every other point *B* in the set, until you find one such that all other points in the set lie to one side of *AB*. This means *B* is an extreme point, so replace *A* with *B* and repeat the procedure. The end result is both the extreme points and the convex hull.

Note the complexity is O(*nh*), where *h* is the number of hull vertices ultimately found. The [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) is more efficient, but it cannot be adapted beyond three dimensions.